# How do i use an Object of IValueConverter from DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter, converters

The DataContext of my WPF application contains an object of an IVariableConverter, which interacts with the DataContext, and is not static

```cs
// Simplified Example
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}

//I am using Fody PropertyChanged
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

   public int someIndex { get; set;}
   // The converter that I want to use, which implements the IValueConverter interface
   public SomeConverter someConverter { get; set; }

  public ViewModel() 
  {
     // ... setting the other variables ... 
     someConverter = new SomeConverter(this, ...);
  }
}
```

Now I have a TextBlock, which uses a binding to the 'someIndex' variable, which I want to convert using the 'someConverter' from the DataContext (which is an object of 'ViewModel')

My best guess would have been to just use the converters name, like a binding, but that unfortunately didn't help

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{binding someIndex, Converter=someConverter}"/>
```

How do i access the converter?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The converter is not supposed to be part of the view model. You would usually declare it as XAML resource and provide it to the Binding by a StaticResource expression like `Text="{Binding someIndex, Converter={StaticResource someConverter}}"`, where `someConverter` is the resource's `x:Key`

Comment: the problem is that i want to initialize it with a few parameters, so that e.g. each button in a list can have their own converter according to a few parameters

Comment: As said, a value converter does not belong to a view model. If you need different converters, declare them in the XAML of your view with different parameters. Alternatively don't use a converter at all and add properties to your view model that directly return the converted values. A converter in a view model will simply not work, because you can't bind the Converter property of a Binding.

Comment: @Clemens is right ! Check this implementation for the IValueConverter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters